# Access store from component

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i have a component and when user click on component it add some value to store,i try to use this way but i get an error :

```
OlapApp.MeasureListItemComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  isDisabled: false,
  attributeBindings: ['isDisabled:disabled'],
  classBindings: ['isDisabled:MeasureListItemDisabled'],

  actions: {
    add: function(measure) {
      var store = this.get('store');
      store.push('OlapApp.AxisModel', {
            uniqueName: measure.uniqueName,
            name: measure.name,
            hierarchyUniqueName: measure.hierarchyUniqueName,
            type: 'row',
            isMeasure: true,
            orderId: 1
      });
    }
  }
});
```

and this is error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined  MeasureListItemComponent.js:18
```

is it posible to push record to store from component? why i cant access to store ? 
my model name is 'AxisModel' and application namespace is 'OlapApp'

Answer (score 43, accepted):

In a `component` the store does not get injected automatically like in `route`'s or `controller`'s when your app starts. This is because components are thought to be more isolated.

> What follows below is not considered a best practice. A component should use data passed into it and not know about it's environment. The best way to handle this case would be using `sendAction` to bubble up what you want to do, and handle the action with the `store` in the controller itself.

@sly7_7 suggestion is a good one, and if you have a lot of components from where you need access to the store then it might be a good way to do it.

Another approach to get to your `store` could be to get the `store` your `component` surrounding `controller` has reference to. In this case it doesn't matter which `controller` this is because every `controller` has already a reference to the `store` injected into it. So now to get to your `store` could be done by getting the `component`'s `targetObject` which will be the `controller` surrounding the `component` and then get the `store`.

### Example:

```
OlapApp.MeasureListItemComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  ...
  actions: {
    add: function(measure) {
      var store = this.get('targetObject.store');
      ...
    }
  }
});
```

See [here](http://jsbin.com/UsiTARu/2/edit) for a working example.

Hope it helps.

### Update in response to your comment having nested components

If for example you child component is only nested one level then you could still refer to parent's targetObject using `parentView`:

```
App.ChildCompComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  storeName: '',
  didInsertElement: function() {
    console.log(this.get('parentView.targetObject.store'));
    this.set('storeName', this.get('parentView.targetObject.store'));
  }
});
```

Updated [example](http://jsbin.com/UsiTARu/4/edit).

Comment: Fine, I was not aware of the component's targetObject. I definitely must update my knowledge about component. I was pretty sure it was really isolated, with no access at all at the controller

Comment: how about sendAction in component ? using sendAction and using event bubling to send action to Route or controller that have store ?

Comment: i have nested component and it dosent work for me. when i log with `console.log(this.get('targetObject.store'))` it say undefined

Comment: im trying to accessing this way to stroe from componet and i can but from view i cant.

Comment: @MBehtemam it seems that `sendAction` is a much better approach to this issue, as components ideally should not fiddle with the `store` directly. I've edited this answer to account for that.

Comment: any chance you could create example using actions?

Comment: But how to do this in the future when controllers are gone?

Answer (score 44):

Since Ember v1.10, the store can be injected to components using initializers, see: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html#toc_injected-properties:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    store: Ember.inject.service()
});
```

Comment: @MBehtemam you may consider marking this one as confirmed solution

Comment: Why is it called `storage` and not `store`?

Comment: That's just a name. You can call it whatever you want within your component (so `store` would work too).

Comment: Documentation states "Use Ember.inject.service() to inject a service with the same name as the property it is injected as".  So I think you would need to do  "store: Ember.inject.service('storage')" @RonniEgeriis

Comment: @J.Barca, you are right. I think storage is an alias for store at the moment  of release of Ember 1.10. Nowadays I would just use `store: Ember.inject.service()`.

Comment: @JacobvanLingen, I ended up using what you put because 'storage' didn't seem to work (I am using mirage for ember-data right now)

Comment: You can also inject in arbitrary named properties the store. Example: `storage: Ember.inject.service('store')`

Answer (score 14):

**Since Ember 2.1.0**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service('store'),
});
```

**before Ember 2.1.0 - dependency injection way**

```
App.MyComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

  store: Ember.computed(function() {
     return this.get('container').lookup('store:main');
  })

});
```

**before Ember 2.1.0 - controller way**

You can pass store as property from controller:

```
App.MyComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

  value: null,
  store: null,
  tagName: "input",

  didInsertElement: function () {

     if (!this.get('store')) {
        throw 'MyComponent requires store for autocomplete feature. Inject as store=store'
     }
  }

});
```

Store is available on each controller. So in parent view you can include component as follows:

```
{{view App.MyComponent
    store=store
    class="some-class"
    elementId="some-id"
    valueBinding="someValue"
}}
```

Passing properties to component is documented [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/)

Comment: This seems like best practice to me, admittedly an Ember newb. +1

Comment: Controllers are being deprecated though.

Comment: But controllers will be deprecated after we get routable components; presumably routable components will get the store injected?

Answer (score 13):

The current ember-cli way to do this appears to be with an initializer. Very similar to the @Sly7_7 answer.

To get a basic model use:

```
  ember g initializer component-store-injector
```

Then edit this to:

```
// app/initializers/component-store-injector.js

export function initialize(container, application) {
  application.inject('component', 'store', 'store:main');
}

export default {
  name: 'component-store-injector',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

I believe this will add the store to all components.

Stolen from https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-todos

Comment: Direct link to the source for [app/initializers/component-store-injector.js](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-todos/blob/f636ca2ef1f952e8fe8e0bff6332f7196c4401ba/app/initializers/component-store-injector.js)

Comment: In ember 1.13, store seems to be registered as service:store.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if components are intended to be used such a way. But if you want, I think you can declare an initializer and inject the store into all components.

```
Ember.onLoad('OlaApp', function(OlaApp) {
  OlapApp.initializer({
    name: 'injectStoreIntoComponents',
    before: 'registerComponents',
    initialize: function(container, application){
      container.register('store:main', App.Store);
      container.injection('component', 'store', 'store:main');
    }
  })
});
```

Here is a contrived but working example: http://jsbin.com/AlIyUDo/6/edit

Comment: Good one, just added my two cents in the case he only needs access to the store in *some* components, but anyway both solutions create dependencies

Comment: I think yours is better :)

Comment: Is this solution working for you? I've tried it but the 'store' property doesn't show up in my components.

Comment: Actually I did'nt test it. So either it's just completely wrong and I should remove, either something is wrong with the initializer. Perhaps it shoud be declare inside an Ember.onLoad() hook. Could you try it and tell me if it works better ?

Comment: @andrei1089 I finally succeed. You need to register the store, and inject it, before the components are registered

Comment: `registerComponents` was renamed to `registerComponentLookup` also `store:main` doesn't have to be registered and will be set after `App.ApplicationStore` is a store class. All these things throw errors now :)

Comment: @K.. can you edit it to provide the updated answer ?

Comment: Actually I don't think that should be considered as a good answer. Component are supposed to be isolated, injecting the store seems to break that. I think the preferred way is to bind an action on the component, and deal with in the controller.

Answer (score 6):

The store can be injected with help of dependency injection.

**Example**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  /**
   *
   */
  store: Ember.inject.service(),

  /**
   * Initialize the component.
   */
  init() {
    this.initialize();

    this._super();
  },

  /**
   * Initialize the properties and prerequisites.
   */
  initialize() {
    // Set the component properties
    this.todos().then((data) => {
      this.set('todoEntries', data);
    });
  },

  /**
   * Returns the todo entries.
   *
   * @returns {*|Promise|Promise.<T>}
   */
  todos() {
    const store = this.get('store');

    return store.findAll('todo');
  },

});
```

Comment: Thank you! Was looking for something like this for a long time! :)

Answer (score 4):

Another way which no one has yet mentioned is to simply pass controller.store to the component e.g.

```
{{my-awesome-component store=controller.store}}
```

Comment: @Marcello: oops missed it - thanks for the correction