# How to test model is successfully added to the store in a components integration test

Tags: ember.js

I have a component that uses `store: Ember.inject.service()` as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29816081/2482265. When the user hits submit a new record in created in the store - e.g:

```
var address = {
  line1: this.get('line1'),
  line2: this.get('line2'),
  line3: this.get('line3'),
  town: this.get('town'),
  county: this.get('county'),
  postCode: this.get('postCode'),
  account: account
};

var record = this.get('store').createRecord('address', address);

record.save().then(() => { ... });
```

I now want to write the integration test for this component, I fill out the fields and then trigger a click on the submit button, thats all fine, but how do I check an address was added to the store?

I saw mention of

```
var container = this.container;
var store = container.lookup('service:store') || container.lookup('store:main');
```

But couldn't work out the last step to give me a useful assert.

**Update**
Some of my components fire an action in `record.save().then()` so I can subscribe to this in the test with a normal `this.on('assertMyAction', () => { ... })`. But some of my components do not need to fire an action back out so I'll need a different way to know store.record.save has forfilled before checking the some of the finer properties on the record.

Comment: Well, record was added to the store when you called createRecord. Do you want to check if it was successfully saved?

Comment: I want to check both, check it was added and also check if it was successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, record was added to the store when you called `createRecord`. I mean it should be added to live arrays, but with property `isNew` set to `true`.

If you want to check if you record was successfully saved you use something like this:

```
let store = lookup('store:main');
assert.equal(store.all('user').get('length'), 1);

store.find('user', userId).then((user) => {
  assert.equal(user.get('isDirty'), false);
  assert.equal(user.get('isNew'), false);
});
```

Before save you should check for `isNew` equal to `true`. After save you could also check for properties such as `isValid`, `isError`. You can find more potentially useful properties [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html).

**Ember 2.0**
You will need to use `this.container.lookup('service:store');` rather than `store:main`

Comment: Thankyou! Some of my components fire an action in the `then` of the record save. So I subscribe to this in the test and check isNew is false etc. Some of my components dont fire such an action however, so I can check the length is 1 like `store.all('user').get('length')`, is there a way to wait for the record to finish saving?

Comment: Because at the moment `user.get('isNew')` comes back true for those components and a simple `setTimeout(() => {...})` isn't cutting it.

Comment: In my tests `Ember.run.later` did the job, but not with records. I think you have to expose some promises or hooks for your tests and then explicitly subscribe to these methods. You could maybe experiment with using didLoad, didUpdate events of model if you have instance of record before firing request. http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#event_didUpdate

Comment: I couldn't get anything to work with the events, I've ended up adding optional actions to the remaining components and then subscribing to those in the tests, feels like there must be a better way though